# Android user statistics logger

Tags: android, image, accessibility, usage-statistics

I'm nearing the end of creating an app that alters images for colour blind users. I'm now wondering how I can collect usage info from all users of the app.

In the app, the user chooses settings based on their specific level and type of colour vision deficiency. The only data I would need to collect is these two values (type and strength), the data would then of course need to be sent to me somehow for analysis.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this, or whether you should do this type of data collection? If this is a how to question then should be more specific about what you need help with. If it's an ethical question, this might not be the best place for this type of question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking HOW to do it. The if part is simply wondering if it's legal to take anonymous user data from apps

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics is good; either that or you have the app post data back to a web server you've set up somewhere.

IF you want to ship into Europe, you'll have to present users with a privacy policy that describes what data you capture and what you do with it, and allow them to opt in or opt out. That's a legal requirement. Probably also a moral requirement I think.

American companies used to bury these kinds of notices about 14 pages deep in an End User License Agreement, and gather all kinds of data. THe European Union now requires a separate Privacy Policy document.

Nothing wrong with collecting the data, as long as you allow users to opt in. Lots of apps gather lots of data for all kinds of purposes. But all the decent and respectable ones provide an opt-in/opt-out option.

Answer (score -1):

have you looked at google analytics ? https://www.google.co.za/analytics/